# How to make Nike arm texture in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture

I want to learn how to make a texture in Illustrator as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Wrinkle tool.

Double click the Wrinkle tool, and set it up like this

[image]

Click and drag on a black filled rectangle, say about 6 times

Change to the Selection Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, then click and drag while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate several times, to make a repeating pattern.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. thank you